# Invoking ApplicationController method in Minitest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

The application's controller has a before action which sets a few methods in sequence (site sets shop, user has roles via a join table)

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_site

protected

  def set_site
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:shop_id].to_i)
    [...]
    role_sets
    current_user_role
  end

  def role_sets
    @operator_roles = [2,3,4,5]
  end

  def current_user_role
    @cu_rsu = Roleshopuser.where('user_id = ? AND shop_id = ?', current_user.id, @shop.id).first
    user_operator?
  end

  def user_operator?
    @user_operator = (!@cu_rsu.nil? && @operator_roles.include?(@cu_rsu.role_id))
  end
```

While the functions work in development mode, the following test fails as some of the instance variables from the controller are handled, others not

```
require 'test_helper'

class ApplicationControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
#  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers  in test_helper

  def current_user
    @current_user
  end

  test 'current_user role' do
    @operators.each do |roleshopuser|
      sign_in roleshopuser.user
puts roleshopuser.role_id
puts @operator_roles
puts @cu_rsu.nil?
      puts user_operator?
    end
  end
```

as evidenced by the minitest response

```
5
2
3
4
5
true
E

Error:
ApplicationControllerTest#test_current_user_role:
NoMethodError: undefined method `user_operator?' for #<ApplicationControllerTest:0x00007fae170d73d0>
```

so `@operator_roles` instance variable is picked up, but `@cu_rsu` is nil, implying that the `current_user_role` method is not invoked. [yes, there is an `@shop` in the setup]

How can ensure a method be called from within a test?

Comment: You really should be asking yourself here  why you're testing a private/protected method - and even more why you're testing its implementation which is extremely smelly. You should really look into for example using Pundit to separate out the authorization logic from your controller if its complex enough to require testing in isolation.

Comment: this is in fact part of a suite of tests that just test access. The complication here is that some access attributes are on the User class while others are on a class which is a joint table of three classes...  Let me understand -a)  tests will/will_not run private/protected methods ? b) is the implication private/protected methods not be tested?

Comment: Testing private/protected methods is generally frowned upon as you're testing the internals of the object and the fact that you want to test these methods in isolation suggests that they do not belong in the controller. In ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest there is no straight forward way to call the methods directly either as it interacts with the controller through HTTP.